# parse string in sql

Tags: sql

I need help parsing `string` of the following pattern for checkin `date` and checkout `date` in `SQL`

```
'CheckIn: Thursday, April 05, 2012
CheckOut: Saturday, April 07, 2012'
```

I tried

```
select 
SUBSTRING([stringToParse], CHARINDEX('Checkin: ', [stringToParse])+9, charindex('<',stringToParse)) as checkin_date,
SUBSTRING([stringToParse], CHARINDEX('CheckOut: ', [stringToParse])+10, LEN([stringToParse])) as checkout_date from xyztable
```

which works for checkout date but when I use similar approach to `parse` checkin it returns

```
'Thursday, April 05, 2012
Chec'
```

I need to parse checkin `date`

Comment: You can't use that approach, what will you do with Monday and Sunday? different lengths...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third argument to substring() is the length, not the offset.  Try this:

```
select  SUBSTRING([stringToParse], CHARINDEX('Checkin: ', [stringToParse])+9, charindex('< br/>',stringToParse)-11) as checkin_date,
        SUBSTRING([stringToParse], CHARINDEX('CheckOut: ', [stringToParse])+10, LEN([stringToParse])) as checkout_date
from (select 'CheckIn: Thursday, April 05, 2012 < br/>CheckOut: Saturday, April 07, 2012' as stringtoparse
     ) t
```

Comment: okay this is just absurd, i was doing the exact same thing, when i do it, i get the error "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

My original query, 
Select [AttributeDescription] , SUBSTRING([AttributeDescription], CHARINDEX('Checkin: ', [AttributeDescription])+9, charindex('<',attributedescription)-11) as checkin_date
      , SUBSTRING([AttributeDescription], CHARINDEX('CheckOut: ', [AttributeDescription])+10, LEN([AttributeDescription])) as checkout_date
  FROM [nop_test].[dbo].[OrderProductVariant]

Comment: @d_nova . . . You have strings that are not in the format you suggest.  You can put in a WHERE clause with "stringtoparse like %CheckIn: %< br/>Checkout%'" to handle only rows with the string in the right fromat.

Comment: u are correct, its throwing an error for string that dont contain the keywords checkin/checkout
putting in a where clause fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server the syntax is

```
SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )
```

So you need to subtract the 9 characters you're offestting at the start from the length to get the right result.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps me to use the len(string) instead of substituting the length value, and to break out each parameter on it's own line.

```
select 
SUBSTRING
(
    stringToParse, -- string
    CharIndex('CheckIn: ', stringToParse) + LEN('CheckIn: '), -- Start
    charindex('< br/>',stringToParse) - /*You want the position of the < br/> MINUS the position of the end of the CheckIn: */(CharIndex('CheckIn: ', stringToParse) + LEN('CheckIn: ')) -- # of characters
) as checkin_date
,
SUBSTRING
(
    stringToParse, 
    CHARINDEX('CheckOut: ', stringToParse)+10, 
    LEN(stringToParse)
) as checkout_date
```

Comment: this works too but needs the where clause to make sure the input strings are in correct format and is much easier to understand because of the comments and indents